# Scheduled Windows Tasks with C# programming

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10

I am trying to use this package: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/ to run a sheduled task on login, forever, every 5 minutes. Unfortinatly its giving me an Access is denied error message when I have done the same with other wrappers? Any help here?

Error Message:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
```

Code:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = TaskService.Instance.NewTask();

    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Handles background work for the XRML application.";

    Trigger wt = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Logon);

    wt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromDays(2000); // last forever
    wt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // every 5 minutes
    td.Triggers.Add(wt);

    td.Actions.Add(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\hello2.txt", "c:\\test.log");

    TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("XRML Helper", td); // just to test
}
```

Comment: Post the *full* exceptino message, including its call stack. Most likely, the application pool's account (by default, a restricted account) doesn't have permission to access or modify the task scheduler service

Answer (score 0):

make sure IIS has enought rights to the folder you want to write to or impersonate a user that does have access

Comment: There's no file access in the OP's code. It's far more likely that tha application pool account doesn't have permission to access the task scheduler

Comment: That could be the case, So use impersonation then.